# I cannot execute trimmomatic on ubuntu

Tags: bash, command-line

```
mohammad@abbasi ~/NGS/Data/RESULTS/TR
$ java -jar ~/NGS/programs/Trimmomatic-0.39/trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE DRR000001_1.fastq DRR000001_2.fastq -baseout GgG.fastq HEADCROP:15 LEADING:30 TRAILING:30 MINLEN:50; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
(base)
```

Comment: It seems the `; done` doesn't belong to the command. What happens if you remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line ends with `; done`, `done` is the shell syntax to end a loop (`for`, `while`, `until`), but you never start any loop.  The shell is confused when it reaches `done` because it doesn't know what loop to terminate.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions?

Comment: @MOHAMMADABBASI: It doesn't appear to be needed, I would just remove `; done` from the end and try running the command like that.  Note that `;` is just a command separator so it doesn't technically need to be removed but wouldn't be needed either way.